# Save Polygons as new Features in geoserver

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs-t

I enabled the functionality to draw Polygons, as in the example. http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/draw-feature.html

Now I want that, once I created a polygon, this polygon is saved as a feature from an underlying WFS layer.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use WFS-T, the T standing for *transactional*, which is what's required to be able to write-back. Both Openlayers and GeoServer support this.

This question may help on the script side - [WFS-T: changes not saved on an OpenLayers map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20565/wfs-t-changes-not-saved-on-an-openlayers-map)

There's also a sample tutorial here:
http://www.gistutor.com/openlayers/22-advanced-openlayers-tutorials/47-openlayers-wfs-t-using-a-geoserver-hosted-postgis-layer.html

Comment: link broken update answer please